# how to order a mysql selection

Tags: mysql

I'm selecting data from two different tables which have a common field "date" and i want to order by date desc but i can't get it to work and i haven't found much help googleing about it.

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.date, table2.id, table2.date FROM table1, table2 ORDER BY
```

Also i would appreciate any links to read more about these types of queries, it would save me from having to ask here for help all the time :D Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want a full-blown cartesian product (where you combine *every* row in table 1 with *every* row in table 2), you'll need a limiting `where` clause, something like:

```
select    a.id, b.id, b.date
from      table1 a, table2 b
where     a.date = b.date
order by  b.date desc
```

The `where` clause in the above `select` will only combine rows from the two tables where the dates are identical, which is what it sounds like you need.

If instead, you want to get the ID and date from two different tables and sort by the date, you probably need something like:

```
select      id, date
from        table1
union all
select      id, date
from        table2
order by    2 desc
```

This will return the IDs and dates from both tables, unioned together, then sort using a column number rather than name.

Comment: a full-blown cartesian product is exactly what i got

Comment: @andrei : then it sounds like the limiting `where` clause is what you need. If the date is a unique key of some sort, it will only return one row for each date (assuming the date is in both tables of course).

Comment: date is the unix timestamp(unlikely that there are any duplicates), i'll try this out now and see what i get

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.date, table2.id, table2.date FROM table1, table2 ORDER BY table1.date
```

An introduction to SQL `ORDER BY` could be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp.

Comment: but i want to take into account both dates, from both tables

Comment: @andrei: you mean the `date` fields of `table1` and `table2` should be the same when selecting them as the case in paxdiablo's answer? Or sort by the larger/smaller one?

Comment: i want to sort the result in the same way as in a regular query, i have the data from both table1 and table2 and using their common field date i want that whole bunch sorted desc (meaning the rows might get mixed in with eachother) // using the where a.date = b.date on my db returns an empty row

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.date, table2.id, table2.date FROM table1, table2 ORDER BY  table2.date DESC
```

if you want to order by table2's date

OR

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.date, table2.id, table2.date FROM table1, table2 ORDER BY  table1.date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use UNION ALL to combine the table queries, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS id, date FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, date FROM table2
) T1
ORDER BY date
```